# On Excel 2015, want to assign a value to a word, "yes" =1,"no"=0

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I made an If statement and place it into the column.

`=IF (H1="yes",0,1)`

This works fine for the individual cell in a column, e.g in column H, cell one.

Then I had to repeat this equation for each cell, changing to H2, H3,H4, etc.

Since I'll have about 300 or more cells, isn't there some other way to do this? repeating the H1 progression out to the nth H value?
The little logic statement above works for the cell H1.  It does not work for H2 because it doesn't refer to H2.  I have to make a statement that works for the entire colum which is H1 to H infinity, or maybe it's H1 and H1 + n but I don't know how to express it mathematically.

Comment: Excel 2015 does not exist.  So what version are you actually using?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-74e31bdd-d993-45da-aa82-35a236c5b5db

Comment: just drag it down through all 300 rows

Comment: There are ways of putting the equivalent formula into many cells. Have you tried those? What is it that you want to do that you can’t do that way? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: you've never drag the cell down and just type them manually?

Comment: Holy cow, you'll be 300x more efficient with @User91504 trick. You should ask for 150x more salary. A win win situation for you and your boss.

Comment: Ramhound I guess it's 2016. I just upgraded to the latest

Comment: Just to make life fore fun.  What if  someone types "YES"  or maybe "Yes", or even "y"?  For your question select the cell and copy it. Then select the other 299 cells and paste.

Comment: cliff2310 program does not seem to care about lower case or upper case as long as the word is "yes".  However a statement about cell H1 is not going to work on H2.  Why would it?

Comment: The reporting program answers "yes" or "no" to questions.  Then users submit data reported as "yes" or "no"  I wanted to convert them into numbers so I could add up the number of "yes" answers.  If I convert the word to a numbe r  I could add the column

Comment: Because the spreadsheet is smart enough to change the 'H1' to the correct cell id (most of the time).  Look up the use of '$'s as in "$H$1" to stop the auto incrementation of the cell address.

Comment: @Deb, Excel is smart enough to change H1 to the appropriate cell reference when you paste the equation.  This is explained in the link that @ Máté posted

Comment: I'm confused by this question. You do know you can put your mouse cursor in the bottom right of a cell (so the mouse changes to a small +) and simply drag down. The fact your writing an off statement suggests you have a working knowledge of Excel. As such you may need to reword your question

Comment: @DebColonyMD - You guess it is Excel 2016.  You should confirm what version it is, then edit your question, after you confirm which version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Why change it at all.  If you want to count how many times "yes" appears in column H, use the COUNTIF function:

```
=COUNTIF(H:H,"yes")
```

If you only want to count some of the rows in column H:

```
=COUNTIF(H1:H300,"yes")
```

The function appears to be case insensitive, so this will also count "YES" and "Yes".

Comment: In the comments below the question, the author specifically states "I wanted to convert them into numbers so I could add up the number of "yes" answers"